# Vue i18n, how to get the locale for the dateTimeLocalization?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-vue-app-with-vue-i18n) on implementing i18n in my vue code. It works perfectly with a small inconvenience. I currently have the language hard-coded. This is how my Localization file looks like:

```
export default: {
    'fr-fr': {
        ...
    },
    'fr-ca': {
        ...
    },
    'en-us': {
        ...
    }
}
```

I specify the locale like so:

```
<td>{{ $d(new Date(date), 'short', 'fr-ca') }}</td>
```

which works fine, but instead of hard-coding it, I would like to be able to get the language that the user has. Something along the lines of :

```
<td>{{ $d(new Date(date), 'short', 'app.i18n.locale') }}</td>
```

or

```
<td>{{ $d(new Date(date), 'short', 'this.$i18n.locale') }}</td>
```

But none of this or the similar changes to it are working.
The fallback is kicking in:

> [vue-i18n] Fall back to 'en' datetime formats from 'this.$i18n.locale datetime formats.

How can I achieve what I want without hard-coding it?

Edit: another example is [this one](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/datetime.html). I have the same code but instead of `'ja-JP'`, I would like to have this automatically taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get the list of preferred languages from the browser and pretend that the first one of them is the most preferred one by the user:

```
var userLanguage = ((navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0]) || '').substr(0, 2);
```

Comment: while this is a good suggestion, I think this is not compatible with my code because I not only need the first two chars, but also the code. so `fr-ca` instead of just `fr`. Furthermore, I believe Vue has a solution to this but I just can't find it.

Comment: Well, you can simply take the full value without `substr()` - in my case the full value was more an inconvenience rather than helpful. I doubt there is a built-in solution for this in `Vue-i18n` but if you know it is there I would like to hear more about that.

Comment: Sure. Any other changes that are needed to get this to work? because I'm getting this error:
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: ((navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0]) || "") is not a constructor"
`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm expecting that you are saving the selected locale to an object 'i18n' under key 'locale'.

Basically your function `$d(new Date(date), 'short', 'app.i18n.locale')` does work, but in your example you have a string where you should have the locale. So change the tick-marks ' to back-ticks `.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    i18n: {"locale": 'fi-FI'}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <p>{{ new Date().toLocaleDateString(`${i18n.locale}`, {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}) }}</p>
</div>
```